# How to Load a Binary File into a Buffer in lua under Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, ios, lua, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am running cocos2d-x 3.2 in the iOS Simulator. I have a binary file "ConfigData.bin" in the root of the app bundle that I want to load into a buffer.
It needs to work on Android.

I am using io.open. It requires the full path to the file, so I am afraid that it will break Android. Is io.open the correct interface, or is do I need to use another method that works with apk's?

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d-x has a `FileUtils` class.

```
std::string fileName = "ConfigData.bin";
std::string filePath = FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(fileName.c_str());
auto fileData = FileUtils::getInstance()->getDataFromFile(filePath);
auto fileDataBytes = fileData.getBytes();
```